# Auto creation of multisite blog on user registration

Tags: multisite, user-registration

I'm looking for a way to have users register on a multisite setup and have a blog automatically created for them... no, not the way the standard ms registration system handles it. I want to get rid of the second step in the process completely. They register as 'user', and a blog is automatically created at http://my.site.com/user for them.

Followup question... anyone know of a way of automatically pruning the multisite platform? IE, users who don't login for 'x' timeframe (or after a certain time period has elapsed) automatically have their site deleted.

Comment: Please only ask **1** question per ... question. Also: There's a WYSIWYG editor and normally, people use `http://example.com` for example links. Else: Welcome to WPSE. :)

Comment: Never really considered a 'proper' format for links... and the second question wasn't really something I'm concerned about at the moment... I really added it more for my benefit than expecting an answer. However, your point is well made. And thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are searching for the [`wpmu_create_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/wpmu_create_blog) function. Just disable the standard registration process and attach this function to the regular registration. [`user_register`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) is a good action hook to do this.

Regarding your second question I don't think there is a built in way. A good start is the [`wpmu_delete_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpmu_delete_blog) function. You could trigger this function on a regular base using [wp-cron](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category%3aWP-Cron_Functions). The information when a blog was updated the last time is stored in `wp_blogs` in the `last_updated` column, but I don't think there is an API function to retrieve this either. So you'll maybe need a custom SQL query to get it.

Answer (score 0):

This [plugin](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/pro-sites/) by WPMU can help you for sure.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Answers! [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.

Comment: While I am a member of wpmudev, I'm not seeing how that particular plugin would resolve my issue...